# how can you build with libTcod on OsX?

Tags: roguelikes

I've had problems building on libtcod on OsX but i'm not the only one (see http://doryen.eptalys.net/forum/index.php?topic=621.0) but the beautiful RL Brogue uses Tcod and even builds on a Mac (https://sites.google.com/site/broguegame/).

anyone else get to developing on OsX with libtcod?  hopefully with Make, not XCode tho...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I emailed Brian Walker and it turns out that they are using a Cocoa wrapper that emulates libtCod, so it looks like the answer is: you can't.